# Outlook VBA gives Run-time error ‘13’: Type mismatch, but the type matches

Tags: vba, outlook, parameter-passing, type-mismatch

I have a `VbaProject.OTM` file that goes along with me across PCs, which contains my own developed code. In a current transfer between PCs, one of the `Sub`s I use a lot stopped working.
I the new PC, it gives `Run-time error ‘13’: Type mismatch`.
The code producing the error is

```
Sub ArchiveConversation()
    Dim objsrc As Object
    Set objsrc = email.GetCurrentItem()
    Dim oOlConv As Outlook.Conversation
    Set oOlConv = objsrc.GetConversation()
    Debug.Print TypeName(oOlConv)           ' <-- Prints "Conversation"
    Call dumpConversation(oOlConv)          ' <-- Error line
    ...
End Sub

Sub dumpConversation(oOlConv As Outlook.Conversation)
    Debug.Print dumpConversationMsg(oOlConv)
End Sub

Public Function dumpConversationMsg(oOlConv As Outlook.Conversation) As String
    Dim straux As String
    straux = "Dumping conversation " & vbCrLf
    dumpConversationMsg = straux
End Function
```

I call a `Sub` which expects an `Outlook.Conversation` parameter.
The argument `oOlConv` passed to the sub is a `Conversation`.

**What could the problem, and solution, be?**

Note:
Currently using Win 10 + MS 16.0 + MS-VBA 7.1, the same as in the PC I am leaving.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the type of object returned by dumpConversationMsg is not a string ?